# Allow user to type any number of strings in Windows Console then show information about number of letters in strings already typed and row number

Tags: c#, arrays, string, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to do Windows Console application which allows user to write any number of letters(string) in one line then after click 'Enter' moving to the next line etc. If user write in console "showme" then it should show him information: row number and number of letters in string in this row (image). There should be also "end" function which should close console, but it's alread done.
My question is how to store typed by user strings and call them from "show" with such a information (i tried with arrays)

I've done something like this but it doesn't work at all.

```
 class Text
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Boolean endless = true;
        ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
        String s;

        while (endless)
        {
            if(Console.ReadLine() == "showme")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("--------------");
            }
            if(Console.ReadLine() == "end")
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
                s = Console.ReadLine() + "\n";
                array.Add(s);
        }

        s = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: You really want this to be in a console application?! If so, I think you should chunk the IF's  and use a case/switch.

Comment: Yep, it must be console app.

Comment: There's no code shown to write back the stored strings. What isn't working exactly?

Comment: You could create your own "UserObject" class and add some properties that the user can add to. Then create your 'Show' method to just readout the properties of your UserObject.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: the stored strings are being added to array.Add(s) @RJ Lohan also why doesn't the OP use a List<string> why the ArrayList..? just curious

Comment: @RJLohan yes it doesn't show stored strings, because they are not stored i guess.

Comment: More unfair downvotes. This is a terrible habit, StackOverflow. The question is 'What am I doing wrong?' and the solution is pretty simple for an experienced programmer, but a little subtle if you are only starting.

Comment: @Fastkowy - there is no code here to print the stored lines back. You have `Console.WriteLine("--------------");` - the array is never read from again.

Comment: @RJLohan right, i would like to know if only construction is good. And also is it good to use ArrayList in this example or something else. I thought u might tell me if it's a good way to go ahead and do what u said :)

Comment: @Fastkowy - you stated 'it doesn't work at all'. The only bit missing I can see is that you aren't printing the captured input strings.

Comment: @RJLohan Yes, but there was also problem after call "showme"(and "---" as test) and "end" functions. I wrote in console "showme" - nothing happened, then did it again and it worked (wrote "---"). So I thought it could while fault.

Comment: @RJLohan The problem is that he is calling Console.ReadLine() 3 times. Look at Inisheer's answer.

Comment: @Oliver - correct. Though neither the question nor answer make it clear that is the problem or the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things:

Consider using a `List<>` vs. `ArrayList` (optional)

Also, you are never adding the value of the `Console.ReadLine()` to the ArrayList because it falls outside of your loop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Consider using a list instead of an ArrayList (optional)
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    while (true)
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (input == "showme")
        {
            // Here we print each string and stats.
            foreach (string s in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s); // Write the line.
                Console.WriteLine("{0} contains {1} letters", s, s.Length); // Write the stats.
            }
        }
        else if (input == "end")
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            // This is where you add your input string to the collection above.
            lines.Add(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, am i right that all functions like "showme" and "end" should be in while()?

Comment: I'd make use of his `endless` boolean to exit the loop, personally.

Comment: There is a line; `array.Add(s);` within the loop. A List might be preferable, but not for any relevant reason; as it doesn't affect the behaviour of the OP's code.

Comment: @RJLohan Correct on both cases. However, I didn't want to overhaul the OPs code too much as I assume too much change will add confusion.

Comment: @Oliver See above comment to RJLohan

Comment: @Inisheer Ok, give me some time so i could analyze it :)

Comment: @Inisheer It's perfect, you completely understood my problem :) This is what i meant. Also thanks to Oliver and RJLohan. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
        if(Console.ReadLine() == "showme")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--------------");
            for(int i =0; i < array.count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Index["+i+"]+" "+array[i]);
            }
        }
```